# Permission denied when calling AWS Lambda function from AWS CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I've set my pipeline to invoke a AWS Lamba function. After a runtime of 10 minutes, this is the error I get:

> Action execution failed The AWS Lambda function addAMIToAutoScalingLC
>   failed to return a result. Check the function to verify that it has
>   permission to call the PutJobSuccessResult action and that it made a
>   call to PutJobSuccessResult.

The logs themselves do not contain relevant informations.

I think my IAM permissions are set-up properly:

- The Lambda function is run with a role that has: `AWSLambdaFullAccess`, `AWSCodePipelineFullAccess`.
- The CodePipeline is I think run with the role `AWS-CodePipeline-Service` that has: `AWSLambdaFullAccess`

I think that my script makes the call to `PutJobSuccessResult` because when I test the script I get a `Execution result: succeeded`.

My script does not need any parameters so I have not provided any User Parameter in CodePipeline.

What should I do to further investigate?

Comment: What sort of authentication you are using here? IAM or resource based?

Comment: I use IAM (I described the rules)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer. The problem did not come from permission, but rather from the absence of call to `PutJobSuccessResult`:
The pipeline did not know that the lambda function was done, so waited until timeout.

This block of code solved the problem (Python):

```
import boto3
pipeline = boto3.client('codepipeline')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # stuff

    response = pipeline.put_job_success_result(
        jobId=event['CodePipeline.job']['id']
    )
    return response
```

Comment: do you know why im getting Lambda doesnt have put_job_success_result attribute when i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the version for python users, in case you missing it.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

  response = pipeline.put_job_success_result(
      job_id = event['CodePipeline.job']['id']
)
   
  return response
```